# Using of Indexed views for data retrival

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, database-design

Our application has over hundreds of Tables in its SQL Server database. Now we want to give the facility for users to write queries for certain areas and retrieve the data. Because the current database architecture is too complicated, I am planning to create a set of simplified indexed views and expose those views to users to write queries against them.

Data in the tables are changing very frequently. Is it ok to use Indexed views for such tables? I don't want to make this feature an overhead to the current functionality.

Can you foresee any issue with this procedure?

Thanks!

Comment: nothing is for free - adding indexed views will add some overhead - whether that is too much will come down to testing.

Comment: Actually sounds like the beginnings of a data warehouse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested my database with some indexed and non-clustered indexed views. Views with clustered index makes the update/delete operations slower in the underneath tables. But that's happens in millisecond range. I understand it depends on the complexity, but this is what I have observed for my scenario.

I ran a update query which update 15000 records.
With indexed view       - 550ms -650ms
Without clustered index – 250ms – 280ms

Our database doesn't have 100s of saving per min. So I think indexed views is suitable for our case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any indexed view will add a performance overhead when tables are inserted/updated (inserted/updated data must be persisted to the indexed view as well). Based on your description of your requirement, I would start with a regular view and only consider indexing the view if performance of these user written queries warrants it.

Comment: @CharithJ - that is a good read, but it really doesn't change anything I've stated. There is still a performance overhead on inserts/updates, which you state happen very frequently; this would have an impact on current functionality. In a data warehouse, you would simply extract the data you want to report on and load it into a a set of denormalized tables that are more suited to reporting.